# I'm using Django and Postgres on Docker, but I can't connect to the database after reinitialising

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

**IMPORTANT NOTE: Django can't RECONNECT to the database. It works, then I try reinitialising it, and it stops working due to what's described below. I can get it to work if I reboot my PC, though.**

I'm running Django and PostgreSQL with Docker Compose (one container for Django and the other for PostgreSQL) I was using the container perfectly with no problems. After typing `sudo docker compose down -v`and `sudo docker compose up -d`, Firefox won't connect, and will show the message:

> The connection was reset

So I run `sudo docker compose logs -f` to check the logs and Django says it can't connect to the Postgres database with the following messages:

> [...]port 5432 failed: Connection refused

> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: seems like your `django` container should wait `postgres` to get ready. how do you start them? can you share `dockerfile` or `entrypoint.sh` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WARNING: back up your data (inside the containers) before trying this.**

Rebuilding everything worked. All I had to do was type `sudo docker compose up -d --build` and I didn't need to reboot my computer for this. While this works, I wouldn't say it's the definitive answer because the **database loses all its data**, but that isn't a problem right now since my app is still in the development stage.